# Php Theme Framework - Theme settings

Tags: javascript, php, frameworks, themes, settings

I have seen redux framework for wordpress and i have used it to develop wordpress themes,

Now im creating a theme for a custom php script   but i want the theme to have admin panel options and settings like change background  layout ....

I see redux framework only work for wordpress,

What alternative opensource framework there is for me to use for my custom script theme?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to use a PHP framework like CodeIgniter or Laravel. Otherwise it won't really do what you need.

Good luck.